# How do I fix "Identifier directly after number" error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

could anyone tell me what's wrong with this code and how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated, thanks. The error is: "null - parsing error: Identifier direcly after number".

```
/**
  * Authorize Google Youtube API.
  */
  var auth = function(immediate, callback) {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(AIzaSyB7xh-QBr-4kpV7RMlYMZ_aUQB5FmfMRLs);
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: 1077089514511-s11blgkep9up7cu7hnq0c84t12ba8ihe.apps.googleusercontent.com,
      scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube,
      immediate: immediate
    }, callback);
  };
```

Here's the other code with the error "ChannelId already defined":

```
var getChannelURI = function() {
    var re = /youtube\.com\/(user|channel|c)\/([^\/]+)/,
        m;
    var channelId = "$"('meta[itemprop=channelId]').attr('content');
    debug(channelId);
    if (channelId) {
      return channelId;
    }
    var channelId = "$"('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content');
    if (channelId) {
      return channelId.match(re)[2];
    }
  };
```

Comment: Your API key has to be a string, as does your client id. That is, "xyz" and not just `xyz`.

Comment: Also your scope and the value for `immediate`.

Comment: Oh wait, not `immediate`, that's a parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, i managed to fix that piece of code. Also this code is part of a larger project, and with the information you gave me i was able to fix all errors with the rest of the code except 1 other piece of code. I'll post it in another comment as there's not enough space. The error for this code is "channelId is already defined". edit: i'll just add it to my original comment

Comment: @Dragon `channelId` is already defined, you don't need to use the `var` keyword the second time. Change `var channelId = "$"('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content')` to `channelId = "$"('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content')`

Comment: Your second question should be a second post. Now that you know the answer you have the luxury of [answering your own StackOverflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208) .

Comment: thanks, i fixed that error, but when i try to run the script there seems to be a function missing. I'll post the full code and maybe you could figure out what the function should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript objects, string values must be wrapped with quotation marks, you can use `"string"` or `'string'`.

This is what your code should look like.

```js
/**
 * Authorize Google Youtube API.
 */
var auth = function (immediate, callback) {
  gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyB7xh-QBr-4kpV7RMlYMZ_aUQB5FmfMRLs");
  gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      client_id:
        "1077089514511-s11blgkep9up7cu7hnq0c84t12ba8ihe.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
      immediate: immediate,
    },
    callback
  );
};
```

[More on JavaScript objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)